# How do you get the number of components in a TwinCAT3 Struct?

Tags: twincat

Is there any function implemented by Beckhoff, which gets you the number of components in any TwinCAT3 Struct?

Comment: Hi Young-Min Kong, welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure if it is possible without some knowledge of the structure. If you know the data types inside the struct, you could figure out the number of elements using the `BitSize` size with [`__VARINFO`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/3527777675.html&id=)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing from Beckhoff itself. There are two methods found by the community though:

1. Do everything in TwinCAT, see [example by benhar-dev](https://github.com/benhar-dev/tc3-count-structure-elements).
2. Combine `NT_Process` function block with a Python script. [Example here](https://www.twincontrols.com/community/twincat-knowledgebase/counting-the-number-of-items-in-a-struct-in-twincat-3-using-python/).